# How to run chained commands in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I want to make a "wrapper" script that will automate a few commands done to a file in the system. I want to run command A to get output, and then use it to run the command B.

Here's where I'm stuck:

```
async function start() {
    const {exec} = require('child_process');
    await exec('adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        var arch = stdout; // x86 
        console.log(stdout);
    });

    await exec('echo ' + arch, (err, arch, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(global.arch);
    });
}

start().then();
```

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Comment: https://zaiste.net/nodejs-child-process-spawn-exec-fork-async-await/

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem.
It talks about chaning one command to the other
I'm talking about saving output of command A to variable, then executing the variable content on command B

Comment: You can stream the stdout from your command to a variable and on the stream end event start start your next command with the data in the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure what you really need. But child processes may have `stderr`, `stdin`, `stdout` streams. You can chain streams by pipe() method.

```
streamA.pipe(streamB)
```

It means data from `streamA` flow into `streamB`.

Updated:

1. If you need to write results in a console:

```
    const { spawn } = require(“child_process”)

    const ls = spawn(“ls”)

    ls.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

`process.stdout` is an exit from your app to a console.

2. If you need to execute `ls | grep index`:

```
    const { spawn } = require(“child_process”)

    const ls = spawn(“ls”)
    const grep = spawn(“grep”, [“index”])

    ls.stdout.pipe(grep.stdin)
    grep.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

3. If you want to type directly in a file from a console

```
    const {createWriteStream} = require(“fs”)

    const write = createWriteStream(“./write-here.md”)

    process.stdin.pipe(write)
```

Now you can type in a console. All typed symbols will be stored in the “write-here.md” file.

Comment: I'm looking for the idiomatic way to perform various operations through the command line in a simple, short nodeJS script. Can you please give me an example? i fail to understand

Comment: I’ll try to write examples after the weekend

Comment: @Amraaronin I've updated this answer with few examples. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use async/await to chain some functions and pass the output of one command to another

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

async function exec1() {
    const child = spawn('ls');

    let ret = '';

    for await (const data of child.stdout) {
        ret += data;
    }
    return ret;
}

async function exec2(out) {
    console.log(out);
    const child = spawn('ls');

    let ret = '';

    for await (const data of child.stdout) {
        ret += data;
    }
    console.log(ret);
}

exec1()
    .then(exec2);
```

Or store that value of the first function to a variable if you like with

```
let output;

exec1()
    .then(out => {
        output = out;
        exec2(out);
    });
```